# BIOS reads twice from different port to the same register in a row

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-16, bios, real-time-clock

I am new to assembly. While trying to figure out what the BIOS does, I use the *gdb* to trace it. However, I found something really strange to me.
The code segment is this:

```
[f000:d129]    0xfd129: mov    eax,0x8f
[f000:d12f]    0xfd12f: out    0x70,al
[f000:d131]    0xfd131: in     al,0x71
[f000:d133]    0xfd133: in     al,0x92
[f000:d135]    0xfd135: or     al,0x2
[f000:d137]    0xfd137: out    0x92,al
```

I wonder why the BIOS reads from port 0x71 and 0x92 in a row. Will the second instruction cover the value read from port 0x71? Then why does it read from port 0x71?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IO port 0x70 is the "CMOS/RTC index register", and IO port 0x71 is the "CMOS/RTC data register". To access something in CMOS you're supposed to set the index then read/write to the data register.

For some RTC chips, if you set the index and don't read or write to the data register the chip is left in an undefined state. This means that if you want to set an index for later you have to read from the data register to avoid "undefined state" between now and later.

In other words; the value that was read isn't relevant - reading causes a side-effect, and it's the side-effect that matters.

Comment: Port 0x70 is also used to disable/enable NMIs, if bit 7 is 0 NMIs are enabled, if bit 7 is 1 then NMIs are disabled. So the code is disabling NMIs and then doing a dummy read of port 0x71 for the reason you gave.

Comment: @RossRidge: It took me years to finally forget the horrendous "ignore catastrophic hardware failures and continue bravely forward unaware" possibility. I'm sad now. ;-)

Comment: Oh yeah - the idea of masking non-maskable interrupts is just evil. We really shouldn't bring this up again. Sigh...

Answer (score 3):

The ports `0x70` and `0x71` are the [CMOS registers](http://wiki.osdev.org/CMOS#Accessing_CMOS_Registers).

The best list I found on this topic [is from the BOCHS emulator](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/techspec/PORTS.LST).
According to this list, the code reads as follows:

```
mov    eax,0x8f   ; sets 'NMI disabled ' and 'CMOS RAM index' = 64
out    0x70,al    ; write
in     al,0x71    ; any write to 0x70 should be followed by an action to 0x71 or the RTC wil be left in an unknown state.
in     al,0x92    ; read PS/2 system control port A
or     al,0x2     ; set BIT1 = indicates A20 active
out    0x92,al    ; write PS/2 system control port A
```

So this code disables the NMI and sets the [A20 line](http://wiki.osdev.org/A20) to an *active* state. The last three lines implement the [Fast A20 Gate](http://wiki.osdev.org/A20#Fast_A20_Gate).

---

> I wonder why the BIOS reads from port 0x71 and 0x92 in a row

The reason simply is that

```
any write to 0070 should be followed by an action to 0071 or the RTC will be left in an unknown state.
```

So the first read(read to `in al,0x71`) does serve no other purpose than assuring this and therefore its result can be ignored.